# Access callback return true, but still is: you are not authorized to this page

Tags: users, entities

```
function updatable_news_menu() {
    $items['updatable_news/test'] = array(
        'title' => 'Updatable news',
        'page callback' => 'updatable_news_test',
        'access callback' => 'updatable_news_permission',
        'access arguments' => "hello",
    );
}
function updatable_news_permission() {
    return true;
}
```

I have used a similar implementation and the permission is ok in another module. However, it fails in this module which defined a brand new entity.

```
function updatable_news_menu() {
    $items['updatable_news'] = array(
        'title' => 'Updatable news root',
        'page callback' => 'updatable_news_root',
        'access arguments' => true,
    );
}
```

I have to add new menu item with access should always be true. But it only succeed for administrator instead of anonymous user and logged in user.

Comment: Take a look at the very end of your hook_menu implementation - is anything missing? Also check the var type of `access arguments` against the documentation

Comment: Gisle Hannemyr-thank you for your help,for first question,I forget to return the menu,and secondly,the 'access arguments'=>true should be 'access callback'=>true.(it is the main reason for my problem)

Answer (score 1):

'access arguments' must be an array. Like `'access arguments' => array('access administration pages')`

Comment: Yes, this is correct, `access arguments` is an array of args passed to the access callback. Note also, to bypass the access check you use `access callback => TRUE` not `access arguments => TRUE`